# How to obtain the asymptotic solution for a ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

How can I obtain an asymptotic solution of $\phi$ when $x\rightarrow\infty$ for the following equation
$$
\biggl[-\frac d {dx^2}+\frac{l(l+1)}{x^2}+\frac{x^2}4+\frac s x-\frac E \omega\biggr]\,\phi(x)=0
$$
I read some notes about obtainig the asymstotic solution but I didn't undrstand how to apply them to my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For large $x$ your equation reduces essentially to
$$
-ϕ''(x)+ \frac{x^2}4  ϕ(x)=0,
$$
all other terms are small perturbations. By the **WKB approximation**, the asymptotic behavior is
$$
 ϕ(x) \sim x^{-1/2}e^{x^2/4}
$$
by the general formula that $-ϕ''(x)+ q(x)  ϕ(x)=0$ has solutions asymptotic to $q(x)^{-1/4}\exp\left(\int\sqrt{q(x)}dx\right)$.

---

A more careful execution of the WKB computations, as noted in the comments by @Maxim,  gives a slight correction for this level of approximation. In the general WKB framework, one tries to find basis solutions in the form $ϕ(x)=e^{S(x)}$. After insertion into the ODE and removal of the exponential factor the equation
$$
-S''-S'^2+\frac{l(l+1)}{x^2}+\frac{x^2}4+\frac s x-\frac E \omega=0
$$
remains.
For large $x$, the derivative terms have also to be large, assume that first and second derivative are of comparable magnitudes so that the square of the first is very large against the second derivative, $S'^2\gg|S''|$. Then balance the two largest terms to get a first approximation $S_0$ with
$$
S_0'^2=\frac{x^2}4\implies S_0=\pm \frac{x^2}4
$$
Now insert $S=S_0+S_1$  to get
$$
S_0''+S_1''+2S_0'S_1'+S_1'^2=\frac{l(l+1)}{x^2}+\frac s x-\frac E \omega
$$
and determine as the leading terms on both sides, from $S_0'\sim x$ we get $S_1'\sim \frac1x$, so that $S_1'^2,S_1''\sim \frac1{x^2}$ are small against the other terms. On the level of constants the reduced equation remains as
$$
S_0''+2S_0'S_1'=-\frac E \omega,\\
\pm\frac12\pm xS_1'=-\frac E \omega,\\
\implies S_1=\left(-\frac12\mp\frac E \omega\right)\ln x.
$$
One could continue further with $S=S_0+S_1+S_2+...$, but the terms quickly become unwieldy. Up to this point, the two basis solutions have the asymptotic form for $x\to\infty$
$$
S_+(x)=x^{-1/2-E/ω}\,e^{x^2/4}~~\text{ and }~~S_-(x)=x^{-1/2+E/ω}\,e^{-x^2/4}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot dear Lutzl. Can you introduce me a reference which has explained your answer in more details?

Comment: You should find enough with searching for "WKB approximation", here and on wikipedia and in physics scripts. This is a standard technique in field theory. Essentially, set $ϕ=e^S$ and expand $S$ into a series of parts that are asymptotically small to the previous one. With $S=S_0+S_1+S_2+...$ this starts with $S_0'^2$ being large against $S_0''$ and then using $S_1$ to correct the main part of the defect of setting $S_0'^2=q(x)$ etc.

Comment: We cannot drop the $E/\omega$ term though, it'll affect the $x^\alpha$ factor in the solution. And if we want asymptotic equivalence, there should also be a constant factor.

Comment: @Maxim : Are you sure that this term is important at $x\to\infty$? The situation is the complete opposite for the analysis around $x\approx 0$.

Comment: Yes, pretty sure. If we substitute $\phi(x) = x^\alpha e^{x^2/4}$ into the ODE, the leading term will be $-x^\alpha e^{x^2/4}(\alpha + E/\omega + 1/2)$.

Comment: @Maxim : Yes, you are correct, one gets this additional exponent either by manually balancing terms as added in the answer, or by noting that $\sqrt{q(x)}=\frac{x}2-\frac{E}{ωx}+O(x^{-2})$.

Comment: @LutzL Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. In fact, I encountered this problem in a paper, but the authors reached the asymptotic solution which is $x^{l+1} e^{-\frac{x^2}4}$. It seems they are wrong because the term including $l$ is eliminated due to $x\rightarrow 0$, right?